# JavaFX Property for a BitSet

Tags: java, properties, javafx, bitset

I need a JavaFX `Property` for a `BitSet` in order to create a `TableColumn` with a toggle button for each bit in the `BitSet`. I have implemented `Property<BitSet>` but even with the oracle documentation the meaning and usage of some of the interface methods still eludes me, as for me this all looks like superfluous boilerplate. Please tell me if I am on the right track with the implementation and what I can improve. I didn't implement bindings yet because I don't expect to need them for my use case.

```
import java.util.*;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;

public class BitSetProperty implements Property<BitSet>
{
    private BitSet  value;
    private final Set<ChangeListener<? super BitSet>> changeListeners = new HashSet<>();
    private final Set<InvalidationListener> invalidationListeners = new HashSet<>();

    @Override public Object getBean() {return value;}

    @Override public String getName() {return "what shall I return here?";}

    @Override public void addListener(ChangeListener<? super BitSet> listener) {changeListeners.add(listener);}

    @Override public void removeListener(ChangeListener<? super BitSet> listener) {changeListeners.remove(listener);}

    @Override public BitSet getValue()
    {
        return (BitSet)value.clone();
    }

    @Override public void addListener(InvalidationListener listener) {invalidationListeners.add(listener);}
    @Override public void removeListener(InvalidationListener listener) {invalidationListeners.remove(listener);}

    @Override public void setValue(BitSet value)
    {
        if(!value.equals(this.value))
        {
            changeListeners.stream().forEach(cl->cl.changed(this, this.value, (BitSet)value.clone()));
            invalidationListeners.stream().forEach(il->il.invalidated(this));
        }
        this.value=value;
    }

    @Override public void bind(ObservableValue<? extends BitSet> observable)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override public void unbind()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override public boolean isBound()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override public void bindBidirectional(Property<BitSet> other)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override public void unbindBidirectional(Property<BitSet> other)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as it turns out I misunderstood how properties work.
I thought they trigger change events when the internal state changes but I know now that they treat the content as a black box (I guess assuming the content is immutable) and just trigger when the content is replaced, which is a much easier problem. My question can then be solved using:

```
ObjectProperty<BitSet> property = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
```